# Can someone explain to me how self join works

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self-join

im really puzzled how self join works and there are only a few examples of selfjoins online and mostly it just shows how to know the manager of an employee in a table. So i have this table

```
ItemCode     ItemNo    ItemTotal
---------------------------------
CT1       |    A     |    20
CT1       |    A     |    30
CT2       |    A     |    40
CT2       |    A     |    10
```

I would like to `Sum()` column `ItemTotal` per `ItemCode` and `ItemNo` and use the `Sum()` to divide it by the original `Itemtotal` per `ItemNo` and `ItemCode`. For example in `ItemCode` CT1 and `ItemNo` `A` the sum of it is 50 and would like to divide it by 20 and 30 which is the original `itemTotal` for `ItemCode` CT1 and `ItemNo` A. The same will happen to the next different `ItemCode` and `ItemNo`. Also if you can provide a explanation that would be helpful. Cheers!

Expected Result

```
ItemCode       ItemNo     ItemTotal
-------------------------------------
CT1       |      A     |    0.4   ----20/50
CT1       |      A     |    0.6   ----30/50 
CT2       |      A     |    0.8
CT2       |      A     |    0.2
```

Comment: Show us the expected result, formatted the same way as your sample data.

Comment: @jarlh edited! I have shorten the table and added my expected result

Comment: The problem with this question is that the title and opening words presuppose that a self-join is a required part of a solution to a problem. Once the problem is actually described, it's clear that self-join is probably not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a single scan of your table:

```
with test(ItemCode, ItemNo, ItemTotal) as
(
  select 'CT1', 'A', 20 from dual union all
  select 'CT1', 'A', 30 from dual union all
  select 'CT2', 'A', 40 from dual union all
  select 'CT2', 'A', 10 from dual 
)
select ItemCode, ItemNo,
       ItemTotal / sum(ItemTotal) over ( partition by ItemCode,ItemNo) 
from test
```

For completeness, if you want a solution with a join, you can use:

```
select ItemCode,ItemNo, t1.ItemTotal / sum(t2.ItemTotal)
from test t1
     inner join test t2 
       using(ItemCode,ItemNo)
group by ItemCode, ItemNo, t1.ItemTotal
```

However the two approaches have different performances; the plan for the join solution:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |     8 |   336 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY      |      |     8 |   336 |     8  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |      |     8 |   336 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |     4 |    84 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |     4 |    84 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and for the single scan solution:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     4 |    84 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT       |      |     4 |    84 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |     4 |    84 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's what I meant!

Comment: @Aleksej Thanks again haha!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle probably has some fancy functionality to do this. But since I don't know Oracle that well, I'll do a simple correlated sub-query answer:

```
select
    ItemCode,
    ItemNo,
    ItemTotal * 1.0 / (
        select SUM(ItemTotal)
        from tablename t2
        where t2.ItemNo = t1.ItemNo
    )
from tablename t1
```

Perhaps you want to do

```
cast(ItemTotal * 1.0 / (
    select SUM(ItemTotal)
    from tablename t2
    where t2.ItemNo = t1.ItemNo
) as decimal(1,1))
```

Comment: I added the Oracle fancy functionality method as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Oracle fancy functionality way of doing this:

```
select ItemCode,
       ItemNo,
       ratio_to_report(ItemTotal) over ( partition by ItemCode,ItemNo) 
from   my_table;
```

Note that this is arguably more robust than:

```
ItemTotal / sum(ItemTotal) over ( partition by ItemCode,ItemNo)
```

... as it implicitly traps division by zero errors and returns null, which would otherwise require:

```
ItemTotal / NullIf(sum(ItemTotal) over ( partition by ItemCode,ItemNo) , 0 )
```